# Keyword not supported: 'provider' in ConnectionString in the web config

Tags: asp.net, web-config

I am having issues accessing my ConnectionString in the web config.

Here is my web config.

```
<configuration>
 <appSettings/>
 <connectionStrings>
    <add name="UAFConnectionString" connectionString="Provider=SQLOLEDB;Data Source=INLISAP003;Password=5q1server2005;User ID=sa;Initial Catalog=UserAccessForm"
   providerName="System.Data.OleDb" />
</connectionStrings>
```

Here is my code for the button click,

```
Imports System.Data
Imports System.Data.SqlClient
Imports System.Configuration
Partial Class _Default

    Inherits System.Web.UI.Page
    Dim mySqlCon As SqlConnection
    Dim strConnection As String

    Sub OpenCon()
        strConnection = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("UAFConnectionString").ConnectionString
        mySqlCon = New SqlConnection(strConnection)
        mySqlCon.Open()
    End Sub

    Sub CloseCon()
        mySqlCon.Close()
        mySqlCon.Dispose()
    End Sub

OpenCon()
            Dim SQL As String = "SELECT * FROM tbl_UserAccount WHERE StafID='" & txtUsername.Text & "' AND Password='" & txtPassword.Text & "' "
            Dim DR As SqlDataReader
            Dim CMD As New SqlCommand(SQL, mySqlCon)
            DR = CMD.ExecuteReader(System.Data.CommandBehavior.CloseConnection)

            DR.Read()
            If DR.HasRows = False Then
                MsgBox("Invalid User name OR Password", MsgBoxStyle.Critical, "Login ERROR")
                txtUsername.Focus()
                Exit Sub
            End If
```

Here is my error message.

> System.ArgumentException: Keyword not
>   supported: 'provider'. at
>   System.Data.Common.DbConnectionOptions.ParseInternal(Hashtable
>   parsetable, String connectionString,
>   Boolean buildChain, Hashtable
>   synonyms, Boolean firstKey) at
>   System.Data.Common.DbConnectionOptions..ctor(String
>   connectionString, Hashtable synonyms,
>   Boolean useOdbcRules) at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnectionString..ctor(String
>   connectionString) at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnectionFactory.CreateConnectionOptions(String
>   connectionString, DbConnectionOptions
>   previous) at
>   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.GetConnectionPoolGroup(String
>   connectionString,
>   DbConnectionPoolGroupOptions
>   poolOptions, DbConnectionOptions&
>   userConnectionOptions) at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.ConnectionString_Set(String
>   value) at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.set_ConnectionString(String
>   value) at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection..ctor(String
>   connectionString) at
>   _Default.OpenCon() in D:\WEB-SITES\PROJECT002\Default.aspx.vb:line 12 at _Default.btnLogin_Click(Object
>   sender, EventArgs e) in
>   D:\WEB-SITES\PROJECT002\Default.aspx.vb:line 35

Comment: CAN YOU PLEASE STOP SHOUTING.. we can hear just fine

Comment: TURN OFF YOUR CAPS LOCK!!!!!  IT LOOKS LIKE YOU'RE SHOUTING!!!!!!

Comment: Mmmh, I can see that it is not PHP.

Comment: Sure you have programming issues, how can you program with caps-lock on?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are already using a specific provider : SLQConnection ! Adding a provider keywork in your connection string is unsupported when using a specific provider. The provider keyword is needed when you use the generic OleDbConnection to let ADO.NET knows which provider to use.

Remove the provider key and its value from your connection string and all should be fine. Or user a OleDbConnection.

Comment: Thanks Eric MORAND, I changed it to OleDbConnection. you the man